# Black Clover chapter at the end of season 3?

Tags: black-clover

I was watching the third season of Black Clover a few days ago and wanted to ask which chapter the third season ends with.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This season finished at chapter 253 if I'm not wrong, From chapter 129 of the anime the episodes aren't canon